# JQuery - How to listen an ID changed button and reset its prop after loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a submit button for a textarea in a modal, and this button set to disabled if the textarea is empty. The code is:

```
function textAreaListener() {
  if (!($(#text-area).val().trim())) {
    $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
  } else {
    $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });
  }
}
```

It works well.

After that, I wrote another method to call the modal, and I need to change the button's id so that the original click event will not happen, I used `$('#submit-button').attr('id','batch-submit-button');` to change button's id, and changed the function above to:

```
function textAreaListener() {
  if (!($(#text-area).val().trim())) {
    $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
    $('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
  } else {
    $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });
    $('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });
  }
}
```

And then the `prop({ disabled: false })` is not working for the button with new id (`#batch-submit-button`), but the older button with old id works well. I looked couple question in StackOverflow and I think the reason is JQuery can't capture the new id after loaded. Is there any way to solve it? Thank you!

------------------Here's my haml file------------------------------

```
#state-modal.modal
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %h5#state-modal-title.modal-title
      .modal-body
        = form_for :proposal, url: '#', html: {id: 'state-modal-form'} do |form|
          = form.text_area :comment, id: 'text-area', |
          placeholder: t('.comment'), class: 'form-control', rows: 5
      .modal-footer
        %button.btn.btn-default{id: 'cancel-button', data: {dismiss: 'modal'}}= t('.cancel')
        %button.btn.btn-primary{id: 'submit-button'}= t('.done')
```

The exact case is:

```
$(function () {
  function initState() {
    $('#state-modal-form').attr('action', '#');
    $('#state-modal-form textarea').val('').hide();
    $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
  }

  function assignHandlersToElements() {
    $(document).on('click', '.commentable-element', App.books.bookCommentableElementHandler);
    $(document).on('keyup', '#state-modal-form textarea', App.books.textAreaListener);
    $(document).on('click', '#cancel-button', App.books.initState);
    $(document).on('click', '#submit-button', App.books.submitHandler);
  }

  function bookCommentableElementHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.target.id == 'selected-button'){
      $('#submit-button').attr('id','batch-submit-button');
      $('#text-area').show();
      $('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
    }else{
      $('#state-modal-form').attr('action', $(this).data('url'));

      $('#text-area').attr('placeholder', 'Comment').show();
      $('#text-area').show()
    }
    $('#state-modal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false }, 'show');
  }

  function textAreaListener() {
    if (!($(this).val().trim())) {
      $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
      $('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
    } else {
      $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });
      $('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });
    }
  }

  function submitHandler() {
    $('#state-modal-form').submit();
  }

  App.books.initState = initState;
  App.books.assignHandlersToElements = assignHandlersToElements;
  App.books.bookCommentableElementHandler = bookCommentableElementHandler;
  App.books.textAreaListener = textAreaListener;
  App.books.submitHandler = submitHandler;
  App.books.assignHandlersToElements();
  App.books.initState();
});
```

Comment: If you have twice this function `textAreaListener` in your file then please remove the first one. I think it is calling the first function.

Comment: You need to understand event delegation : https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Use on() method that will fire your textAreaListener() function

Comment: @AlokMali Hi Alok, I only have one ```textAreaListener```, the following ```textAreaListener()``` is the one I modified.

Comment: @PHPnoob Thank you. I'll look at it now. I set a debugger on else block, it runs into this block but the ```$('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });``` is not working.

Comment: Could you please add your HTML as well. So that we can figure out the issue.

Comment: @AlokMali Hi, I use haml to render it, and I have added it into my question, thank you!

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have the button with Id `batch-submit-button`

Comment: @AlokMali Yes, that's why I said I changed the id based on my needs in my question... I used ```$('#submit-button').attr('id','batch-submit-button');``` in my other method.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simulated your code on my side.
And prop({disabled: false }); is working for id changed button.
Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
<button id="disable_btn">Disable</button>
<button id="enable_btn">Enable</button>
<button id="change_id">Change ID</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#disable_btn").click(function(){
        $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
        $('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: true });
    });

    $("#enable_btn").click(function(){
        $('#submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });
        $('#batch-submit-button').prop({ disabled: false });
    });

    $("#change_id").click(function(){
        $('#submit-button').attr('id', 'batch-submit-button');
    });
});
```

Please provide your exact case.

Comment: Thank you, I just provided my case, could you look at it if you have a chance?

Comment: Please check again you used correct selectors for assignHandlersToElements function. 'commentable-element', 'cancel-button', 'submit-button'

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake when I copy and simplified the code on StackOverflow, the selector is correct in my code. And I just edited it in question description.

Comment: I simulated with your latest code and it still works for #batch-sumit-button. If you can, please provide your url.

Comment: I just figure out why, the reason is I give the wrong id with the inverse characters.. I'm stupid..Anyway, I want to thank you for your help and have a good day